# Range in for loop using Array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, numbers, integer

I'm pretty new to C# and want the users to be able to write in 5 numbers between 1 to 25. The issue I'm having is that I don't want the user to type a number over 25 or a number below 1.

Also this is a task for my studies and my teacher want us to use arrays so I'm not allowed to use List.

```
        int[] usernum = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < usernum.Length; i++)
        {
            usernum[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if you want your user not be able to enter a number lower then 1 or higher than 25 you need to check for that.

Comment: If you want 5 values, your array should have length 5, not 4.

Comment: I would advise you to first look into If statements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else and trying to understand how to solve it yourself instead of asking for help.

Comment: Also, do not use `Convert.ToInt32`, use `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would recommend you to learn if else loop first https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_conditions.asp

here is the code if needed

```
int[] usernum = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < usernum.Length; i++)
        {
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            int currentResult;
            if (!int.TryParse(result, out currentResult))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input - must be a valid integer value");
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            if(currentResult < 1 || currentResult > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input - must be between 1 & 25");
                i--;
                continue;
            }
            usernum[i] = currentResult;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks legend. This helped, I know how if/else works.I don't quite understand all of the code you gave me so I will have some studying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, to start off, some annotations to your code:

```
int[] usernum = new int[4]; // should be: new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < usernum.Length; i++)
{
    usernum[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // use int.TryParse instead
}
```

Now, I don't want to just give you the code, since this should obviously be a learning experience.

What you need to *do*, though is integrate a "validation" cycle. That means:

1. Read in string from user
2. Try to parse string to number 
   If that fails: back to 1.
3. Check `if` number < 1 or > 25
   If so: back to 1.
4. If you are here, you passed both checks and can
   set usernum[i] = number
5. Next "i"

Obviously, there are some slight variations in how you twist and turn your checks and arrange loops which are equally valid.

For example: You can decide if you want to check if number is *inside* bounds or if you want to check if the number is *outside* bounds and jump or not jump accordingly ...

---

Why `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`?

There are some rule of thumbs that can spare you from severe headaches:

- "Never trust user input"
- "Do not use exceptions for control flow"

Using Convert here, breaks both.

For one, Convert.ToInt32 throws if the string does not represent an integer value (chars other than +-0..9, value > int.Max or < int.Min). So in using it, you trust the user to type in a valid integer. Not a good idea.

Then, it throwing means: the case, that a user (maybe just made a typo) did not provide valid input is controlling your flow to error handling. But this case is not at all "exceptional". In fact, you *should* expect it. `int.TryParse` makes this possible, in that it returns you a flag (boolean) that informs you about success or failure of the conversion attempt (instead of throwing).

Comment: Thanks mate. I will try this out and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`for-loop` might not be the ideal solution for this use-case where you need to conditionally increment the index.

This should do the trick:

```
int[] userNumbers = new int[5];

int i = 0;

while (i < userNumbers.Length)
{
    string rawInput = Console.ReadLine();
    
    bool isNumberValid = int.TryParse(rawInput, out int inputNumber); // as suggested by @Fildor
    
    if(isNumberValid && inputNumber >= 1 && inputNumber <= 25) // increment counter only if 1 <= input <= 25
    {
        userNumbers[i] = inputNumber;
        i++;
    }
}
```